# Where to use Multi threading concept

Tags: java, multithreading

I have one requirement to update the 300 000 records which is available in the database.When I wrote a standalone program its took 25-30 mins to update 5 000 records. so to finishing all the records it may take 30 hours. Then I thought I will write a multi-threading program. I created 2 threads then I started updating, its took the same time means 30 min for 5k records.

As of my knowledge we are using the thread for concurrent access of a method and it will not speed up the update in this case.

For the above scenario what I have to do to decrease the time. And what is the actual use of Multi-threading

```
   class MyThread1 extends Thread{
    public static String getTaskID(String PID)
    {
        String taskID = OurGenerator.orgPID(PID);
        return taskID;
    }
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pstmt;
    BufferedReader bf;
    MyThread1(Connection con,PreparedStatement pstmt){
        this.con=con;
        this.pstmt=pstmt;
        try {
            bf=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/prod_review_sifid3.txt"));
        }catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("IO Error Occurred: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
    public void run(){
        String line;
        try{
          while (( line = bf.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String taskID = getTaskID(line);
                   pstmt.setString(1,taskID);
                   pstmt.setString(2,line);
                   pstmt.executeUpdate();

          }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
class MyThread2 extends Thread{
    public static String getTaskID(String PID)
    {
        String taskID = OurGenerator.orgPID(PID);
        return taskID;
    }
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pstmt;
    BufferedReader bf;
    MyThread2(Connection con,PreparedStatement pstmt){
        this.con=con;
        this.pstmt=pstmt;
        try {
            bf=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/sifid_review2.txt"));
        }catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("IO Error Occurred: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
    public void run(){
        String line;
        try{
          while (( line = bf.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String taskID = getTaskID(line);
                   pstmt.setString(1,taskID);
                   pstmt.setString(2,line);
                   pstmt.executeUpdate();

          }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}

public class SifuuidInsert {
  public static void main(String ar[])throws Exception{
      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
      Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("","","");
      PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("update Taskdata set taskID=? where entryid=?");
        MyThread1 first=new MyThread1(con,pstmt);
        first.start();
        MyThread2 second=new MyThread2(con,pstmt);
        second.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: It really depends on what's happening in your `run()` methods.

Comment: String line;
  try{
    while (( line = bf.readLine()) != null)
         {
    String sifID = getSIFID(line);//lines means one id
    //i am readind that id from a text file where 3 lakhs id is there
       pstmt.setString(1,sifUUID);
       pstmt.setString(2,line);
       pstmt.executeUpdate();
    
       }
  }catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: Could you please add the code to your question? This way we can e.g. see scopes.

Comment: Hi @mad_manny i added the code

Comment: Each thread should obtain its own connection and create/use its own prepared statement. Otherwise in best case threads are stalled at driver and in worse case program has undefined behaviour - crashes, partial updates, corruption of db data etc.

Comment: You may want to pass the input file path to the your thread instance instead of writing the same code two times with the path difference.

Answer (score 0):

First: Use a batch update to add queries and push in the end of the set, Info [here (general)](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/batchupdate.html) and [here (for oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/oraperf.htm)

Second:  Your are repeating a class implementation just for a new file, just add a parameter for the class that receives the path of the file.

```
class MyThrea extends Thread {
    public static String getTaskID(String PID) {
        String taskID = OurGenerator.orgPID(PID);
        return taskID;
    }

    Connection con;
    BufferedReader bf;

    MyThread1(Connection con, String path) {
        this.con = con;
        this.pstmt = pstmt;
        try {
            bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Error Occurred: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void run() {

        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("update Taskdata set taskID=? where entryid=?");
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                String taskID = getTaskID(line);
                pstmt.setString(1, taskID);
                pstmt.setString(2, line);
                pstmt.addBatch();
            }

            pstmt.executeBatch();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public class SifuuidInsert {
    public static void main(String ar[]) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("", "", "");
        MyThread first = new MyThread1(con, "path_to_file_1");
        first.start();
        MyThread second = new MyThread1(con, "path_to_file_2");
        second.start();
    }
}
```

it could be improved by loading first the file, then execute the update.

Answer (score 0):

Much of the work of a database update happens on the server. Depending on the database and the configuration of your particular server, it might help to present the server with multiple streams of work -- or it might hurt, or it might not change the performance at all.

Mostly, however, it won't help unless each thread has its own independent connection to the database.

Answer (score -1):

MultiTherading is used for concurrent  access and not for time and performance purpose. you should try bulk update directly by updating some similar records

Comment: Ys i am thinking same too. But same program if i am running on 5 different machine then records are updating faster as it is multiple process may be. then how i will do the same in one machine in same  program.

Comment: then in this case, I agree to bmargulies's answer. Try to connect every thread with independent connection to database.